# How to manage app admins within FB Business Manager?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps

Lets say your company has a Facebook Business Manager. One of your employees has created hundreds of FB-apps in his or her name, but they are all owned by the Business Manager.

I thought that Business Manager could work like an admin for all the apps, with the possibility to give other users access, but no - when your employee leaves the company, he or she has to grant access to another member of the company for all the apps.

Is there not a better way to solve this with Business Manager? Any help will be greatly appreciated!